Getting generic malformed body error response on ARM template deployment
I'm working towards deploying azure DevOps build agents on azure container apps jobs and when deploying using an ARM templating I'm getting the below generic error message:
WARNING: Default enabled including preview versions for extension installation now. Disabled in future release. Use '--allow-preview true' to enable it specifically if needed. Use '--allow-preview false' to install stable version only. 
WARNING: The installed extension 'containerapp' is in preview.
ERROR: {"code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment", "message": "The template deployment 'containerapp' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '372358fe-1076-4b96-ae3c-b4b6abbd987e'. See inner errors for details."}

Inner Errors: 
{"code": "ValidationForResourceFailed", "message": "Validation failed for a resource. Check 'Error.Details[0]' for more information."}

Inner Errors: 
{"code": "ContainerAppsJobInvalidSchema", "message": "Invalid request body for container apps job. Does not conform to Container Apps Job schema, please visit for more information https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/container-apps/azure-resource-manager-api-spec?tabs=arm-template#container-app"}

I've reviewed the documentation, and I can't find a difference between what I'm building and their documentation.
Template:
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "environmentName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "azpUrl": {
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "azpToken": {
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "azpPool": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "azpPoolId": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "registrayLoginServer": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "registryUsername": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "registryPassword": {
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "image": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "scaleOn": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "minReplicas": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "maxReplicas": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "cpu": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "memory": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "containerAppName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.App/jobs",
            "name": "[parameters('containerAppName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "None"
            },
            "properties": {
                "environmentId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments', parameters('environmentName'))]",
                "configuration": {
                    "triggerType": "Event",
                    "replicaTimeout": 1800,
                    "replicaRetryLimit": 1,
                    "secrets": [
                        {
                            "name": "azp-url",
                            "value": "[parameters('azpUrl')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "azp-token",
                            "value": "[parameters('azpToken')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "registry-password",
                            "value": "[parameters('registryPassword')]"
                        }
                    ],
                    "registries": [
                        {
                            "server": "[parameters('registrayLoginServer')]",
                            "username": "[parameters('registryUsername')]",
                            "passwordSecretRef": "registry-password"
                        }
                    ],
                    "eventTriggerConfig": {
                        "parallelism": 1,
                        "replicaCompletionCount": 1,
                        "scale": {
                            "minExecutions": "[parameters('minReplicas')]",
                            "maxExecutions": "[parameters('maxReplicas')]",
                            "pollingInterval": 10,
                            "rules": [
                                {
                                    "name": "azure-pipelines-scale-rule",
                                    "auth": [
                                        {
                                            "secretRef": "azp-token",
                                            "triggerParameter": "personalAccessToken"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "secretRef": "azp-url",
                                            "triggerParameter": "organizationURL"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "type": "azure-pipelines",
                                    "metadata": {
                                        "organizationURL": "[parameters('azpUrl')]",
                                        "poolID": "[string(parameters('azpPoolId'))]",
                                        "targetPipelinesQueueLength": "[string(parameters('scaleOn'))]"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "template": {
                    "containers": [
                        {
                            "image": "[parameters('image')]",
                            "imageType": "ContainerImage",
                            "name": "azure-pipelines-agent",
                            "env": [
                                {
                                    "name": "AZP_URL",
                                    "secretRef": "azp-url"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "AZP_TOKEN",
                                    "secretRef": "azp-token"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "AZP_POOL",
                                    "value": "[parameters('azpPool')]"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "AZP_POOLID",
                                    "value": "[parameters('azpPoolId')]"
                                }
                            ],
                            "resources": {
                                "cpu": "[parameters('cpu')]",
                                "memory": "[parameters('memory')]",
                                "ephemeralStorage": "50Gi"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


Here is the code I'm using to execute the above Arm Deployment:
#!/bin/bash

# Set POOLID based on deploymentPurpose
if [[ "${{ parameters.deploymentPurpose }}" == "DEV" ]]; then
  POOLID=17
elif [[ "${{ parameters.deploymentPurpose }}" == "Test" ]]; then
  POOLID=16
elif [[ "${{ parameters.deploymentPurpose }}" == "PROD" ]]; then
  POOLID=14
else
  POOLID=15
fi
echo "POOLID is set to $POOLID"

az extension add --name containerapp --yes

az provider register --namespace Microsoft.App

# Wait until the namespace registration is completed
while ! az provider show -n Microsoft.App --query "registrationState" -o tsv | grep -q "Registered"; do
  echo "Waiting for Microsoft.App namespace registration to complete..."
  sleep 10
done

AZP_URL="URL"
AZP_TOKEN=$(pattoken)
AZP_AGENT_NAME=${{ parameters.deploymentPurpose }}
AZP_POOL=${{ parameters.deploymentPurpose }}
REGISTRY_USERNAME=USERNAME
REGISTRY_PASSWORD=$(acrpassword)
REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER=ACRURL
IMAGE=IMAGEURL

CONTAINER_APP_NAME="devops-agent-$(echo "${{ parameters.deploymentPurpose }}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"
MIN_REPLICAS="${{ parameters.minReplicas }}"
MAX_REPLICAS="${{ parameters.maxReplicas }}"
CPU="${{ parameters.cpu }}"
MEMORY="${{ parameters.memory }}Gi"
SCALE_ON="${{ parameters.scalePoint }}"

az deployment group create \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --template-file "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/DevOps/DevopsAgent/ContainerApp/containerapp.json" \
    --parameters \
        environmentName="$CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT" \
        location="$REGION" \
        azpUrl="$AZP_URL" \
        azpToken="$AZP_TOKEN" \
        azpPool="$AZP_POOL" \
        azpPoolId="$POOLID" \
        registrayLoginServer=$REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER \
        registryUsername=$REGISTRY_USERNAME \
        registryPassword=$REGISTRY_PASSWORD \
        image=$IMAGE \
        scaleOn=$SCALE_ON \
        minReplicas=$MIN_REPLICAS \
        maxReplicas=$MAX_REPLICAS \
        cpu=$CPU \
        memory=$MEMORY \
        containerAppName=$CONTAINER_APP_NAME

I would appreciate it more than anything if someone could point out what is wrong with my template.
I did a deployment with the below commmand:
az containerapp job create \
                  --name "$CONTAINER_APP_NAME" \
                  --resource-group "$RESOURCE_GROUP" \
                  --environment "$CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT" \
                  --trigger-type "Event" \
                  --replica-timeout 1800 \
                  --replica-retry-limit 1 \
                  --registry-server "$REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER" \
                  --registry-username "$REGISTRY_USERNAME" \
                  --registry-password "$REGISTRY_PASSWORD" \
                  --image "$IMAGE" \
                  --cpu "$CPU" \
                  --memory "$MEMORY" \
                  --min-executions "$MIN_REPLICAS" \
                  --max-executions "$MAX_REPLICAS" \
                  --scale-rule-name "azure-pipelines-scale-rule" \
                  --scale-rule-type "azure-pipelines" \
                  --scale-rule-metadata "poolID=$POOLID" "targetPipelinesQueueLength=$SCALE_ON" \
                  --scale-rule-auth "personalAccessToken=secretref:azp-token" "organizationURL=secretref:azp-url" \
                  --secrets "azp-url=$AZP_URL" "azp-token=$AZP_TOKEN" \
                  --env-vars "AZP_URL=secretref:azp-url" "AZP_TOKEN=secretref:azp-token" "AZP_POOL=$AZP_POOL" "AZP_POOLID=$POOLID" "AZP_AGENT_NAME=$AZP_AGENT_NAME"

This worked and I matched the output to my template and didn't see any differences in the Schema.

Turns out that the Microsoft.App/Jobs API with version 2023-05-01 and the newer previous version require all parameter inputs to be strings even if they are numbers.  I was able to successfully create this by making all parameters of type string.
